# Symbol required to enter date in text strings

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working on a homework assignment for school, and I have come across one particular question which has me a little stumped. The question is, 11.    What symbol does Access SQL require to enter dates in text strings? I have found the use of ''(single quotes), " " (double quotes), and #(pound sign), but I have not been able to find a definitive answer to this particular questions. Which would be the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is homework, I'll show you how to find the answer you need.

Open the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>) and run both of these statements (pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each):

```vb
Debug.Print TypeName("5/2/2013")
Debug.Print TypeName(#5/2/2013#)
```

However it's safer to use *yyyy/m/d* format with literal date values to avoid locale issues ... ie does 5/2/2013 represent May 2nd or Feb 5th?

```vb
Debug.Print TypeName("2013/5/2")
Debug.Print TypeName(#2013/5/2#)
```

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea you could do that in Access. Looks like my answer is double quotes then

Comment: Hmm.  `#` is the date delimiter. Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I see what you mean. Is there many people who would read that date as Feb 5th?

Comment: This question has me stumped a little bit. It's really the wording of the question is off

Comment: When you first mentioned string, I thought a string holding a SQL statement: `SELECT * FROM tblFoo WHERE date_field = #2013-5-2#;`  The `#` delimiter is the appropriate choice there.  But if you just want a string which contains the text representation of a date, use double quotes in VBA and double or single quotes in SQL statements.

Comment: Actually, [most of the world uses d/m/y](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)...and nobody except the US and Belize uses m/d/y :-)